# html not printing out the way I expect it to in the webpage source

Tags: php, html, return, echo

Can some one show me, keeping the same level of abstraction, how to do this properly? I have these two basic classes, that don't do as I want. The end resualt should be:

```
<div class="test">
    content
</div>
```

**If I do it this way:**

```
class Wrapper{

    protected $_html = '';

    public function open(){
        $this->_html .= '<div class="test">';
    }

    public function close(){
        $this->_html .= '</div>';
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
    }
}

class Content{

    protected $hmtl .= '';

    public function content(){
      $wrapper = new Wrapper();
      $wrapper->open();
      $this->html .= 'test';
      $wrapper->close();
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
    }
}
```

$content  = new Content();
echo $content->content();

I get, and yes this is from the source:

```
"content";
```

**If I do it this way:**

```
class Wrapper{

    protected $_html = '';

    public function open(){
        echo $this->_html .= '<div class="test">';
    }

    public function close(){
        echo $this->_html .= '</div>';
    }

    // Technically don't need this
    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
    }
}
```

I get, and yes this is from the source,

```
<div class="test"></div>
"content"
```

So what am I doing wrong? and how do I keep the same level of abstraction and get the desired output?

Comment: protected $hmtl <- you have a typo. it should be $html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want some kind of method to add content into the wrapper such as

```
public function addContent($content){
        $this->_html .= $content;
    }
```

and you can do this by

```
$wrapper = new Wrapper();
$content = new Content();
$wrapper->open();
$wrapper->addContent((string)$content);
$Wrapper->Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never invoking the `Wrapper` classes `__toString` method which would yield the HTML markup. I think what you actually want is something like `$this->_html = (string)$wrapper->open()` for it to appear.

**EDIT**:

Actually, the entire logic of your setup eludes me. Why do you not `return` from the ->open() and ->close() methods instead?