# return, echo and using php to create forms

Tags: php, html, forms, return, echo

This question builds upon the [previous question I asked which is similar in nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862845/html-not-printing-out-the-way-i-expect-it-to-in-the-webpage-source/14862922#14862946) This question is a two part question concerning the way html is out put to the screen, based on the class bellow.

Based on the answer to that question I created the following:

```
class Form{

    protected $_html = '';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init(){

    }

    public function open_form(){
        $this->_html .= '<form>';
    }

    public function elements(){
        $this->_html .= 'element';
    }

    public function close_form(){
        $this->_html .= '</form>';
    }

    public function create_form(){
        $this->open_form();
        $this->elements();
        $this->close_form();
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
    }
}
```

The problem with this class is that if I do:

```
$form = new Form
echo $form->create_form();
```

Then nothing gets printed out. How ever if I change create_form to do the following:

```
    public function create_form(){
        $this->open_form();
        $this->elements();
        $this->close_form();

        echo $this->_html;    
    }
```

Then it works and I see:

```
<form>elements</form>
```

**Why is this? and how would I fix it?**

The second part to this question is that I have a function, and no I **cannot change the out put of this function** that **echoes** hidden fields into a form. The problem is if I do:

```
    public function create_form(){
        $this->open_form();
        $this->elements();
        function_echoes_hidden_fields();
        $this->close_form();

        echo $this->_html;    
    }

    // Sample function to echo hidden fields.
    public function function_echoes_hidden_fields(){
        echo "hidden fields";
    }
```

I now see:

```
"hidden fields"
<form>elements</form>
```

**How would you fix this problem?**

What I know is that return, returns a value for further processing, meaning you have to echo out the function that returns the value if you want to display that value, while echo will escape processing imediatly and echo out the value.

My problem is, I am trying to use them together, to create a form.

Comment: `create_form` doesn't return anything so `echo $form->create_form();` does nothing.

Comment: Also `echo` does **NOT** "escape processing immediately".  It `echo`s out the value, then continues on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call create_form and then echo the class.

```
$form = new Form
$form->create_form();
echo $form;
```

or add `return $this->_html;` to create_form() and your existing code will work.

Comment: This isnt the right answer either but ill just accept it for the sake of it

Answer (score 1):

change `create_form` to

```
public function create_form(){
        $this->open_form();
        $this->elements();
        $this->close_form();
        return $this->_html;
    }
```

change function_echoes_hidden_fields to

```
public function function_echoes_hidden_fields(){
        $this->_html .= 'hidden fields';
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
or create a new class

```
class newFrom extends Form{
public function get_form()
{
        return $this->_html;
}
public function create_form(){
    $this->open_form();
    $this->elements();
    $this->function_echoes_hidden_fields()
    $this->close_form();

    return $this->_html;
}
public function function_echoes_hidden_fields(){
    $this->_html .= 'hidden fields';
}
};
$form = new newFrom;
$form->create_form();
echo $form->get_form();
```

Comment: problem with your solution, this function is internal API, I cannot change it - as the API may change in the future. Any other ideas? (The function in question is a WordPress function: `settings_fields` see me: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_fields)

Comment: Your updated answer does not help or explain how I am suppose to call a function, which cannot be changed, and echoes the hidden fields, in between open_form() and close_form() functions. All it does is just echo's a form.....Where does the function that echo's the hidden fields come into play?

Comment: @Kyle Adams you can redeclare create_form() in newfrom class , i add new method in my answer

Comment: you still are not reading what I wrote, your function_echos_hidden_fields, CANNOT be chnaged as you put it. it is internal API that I cannot change, all it does is echo. thi is the wrong answer

Comment: you still are not reading my answer ! yes it is api , i accept, you can in your server NOT in api , declare newform class , and redeclare function_echos_hidden_fields that return html istead of echo

Comment: $form = new Form
echo $form->create_form(); is in your server , ok ? instead of $form = new Form use $form = new newForm, and declare newForm with new function